# JavaFX 8 not working in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 8.0 but in JavaFX 8(simple), and 3D applications are not running successfully. It shows an error:

```
Gen6+ requires Kernel 3.6 or later.
java: ../../../../../src/mesa/main/context.c:1501: _mesa_make_current: Assertion `newCtx->Version > 0' failed.
Java Result: 134
```

What should I do now as JavaFX 3D applications always works on Windows when my nVidia Driver is successfully installed. I have checked the Additional Drivers but its showing installed and active for nVidia.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in your message **Gen6+ requires Kernel 3.6 or later** is your problem. So you are trying to use software that is too new for your operating system. You can check the kernel you are using with

```
uname -a
```

See the table of releases at the [bottom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases) of the wikipedia page about our releases:

```
Version Kernel
12.04   3.2 or newer
12.10   3.5
13.10   3.11
14.04   3.13
```

It is possible to install the 3.6 kernel in 12.04 but better would be to install 14.04.